# Need to be able to set the Azure AD proxyaddress through an API. Is this available?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, alias

We want users to be able to set their own proxyaddress (alias) email. Is there an API or third party took that will allow this self service?

If not, we can do with the Azure AD Powershell?

I looked at the MSGraph but did not see that this could be set, is that correct?

I don't have experience setting this, but if there are no tools to do it or its not available on an existing API and we can set it some other way, I was thinking of making a logic app api to manage it.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

Please **note** that, to set the Email Alias to any user, the user must have assigned licenses (**`Office 365 E5/F3`**).

***If the user doesn't have required licenses, then the Email Alias won't be available for that user:***

[image]

To set Proxy address (alias) email to user, one must have **Admin permissions** to perform the action.

Execute the **PowerShell commands** by connecting to Exchange Online like below:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

#Setting Proxy address for the user
Set-Mailbox UPNOfUser -EmailAddresses @{add="Proxy address"}

#Getting the User Proxy address
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId ObjectIDofUser| ft proxyAddresses
```

[image]

I tried to connect to the **Exchange Online PowerShell using the User credentials** and got the random error like below:

[image]

You can also set the Proxy address via [**Microsoft 365 admin center**](https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal/home#/users/:/UserDetails/21a8d6aa-1527-42ea-b7c4-3edce806e75e/LicensesAndApps) like below:

*Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Users -> Active Users -> Click on the required user -> Manage username and email*

[image]

Please **note** that, to set the Proxy address (alias) email attribute in PowerShell/Graph API/Admin Portal the user must have **Admin role**.  The user without the **Admin Privileges** cannot perform this action in any method.

Comment: Make sense. We want some users that do not have admin rights to be able to set this for themselves. Can we wrap this in an azure function to allow a non admin user access to change their own?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible for non admin user to set proxy address for themselves.

Comment: Right, not directly. If we create an Azure Function that authenticates the user and uses a service account to perform the action I think we can make it work. Expose that as an api call (secure it properly) and we can use that in apps.